# How to refer to a complex type in XML schema with no targetNamespace

Tags: xml, oracle11g, xsd, soa, bpel

At the moment, I'm implementing a number of interfaces to consume XML data from external systems. The data I'm supposed to receive are all well-formed XML documents. However, the problem is that they all come without namespaces like the sample below.

```
<ReturnOfFileApplicationDetails>
   <ApplicationNo>APP-2015-1214-000847</ApplicationNo>
   <CourtOrderRefNo></CourtOrderRefNo>
   <SourceRequestNo></SourceRequestNo>
   <Status>A</Status>
   <RejectionReason></RejectionReason>
   <CourtEventDetails>
      <NextCourtNo>26</NextCourtNo>
      <NextCourtDateTime>201601111500</NextCourtDateTime>
      <NextCourtJOName></NextCourtJOName>
   </CourtEventDetails>
   <IODetails>
      <Name>CPIB IO</Name>
      <Designation>Special Investigation Officer</Designation>
      <DivisionAgency>CPIB</DivisionAgency>
      <ReportNo></ReportNo>
      <IPNo></IPNo>
   </IODetails>
</ReturnOfFileApplicationDetails>
```

Hence, from what I've learnt so far, I cannot use `targetNamespace` in the XSD schema I built to describe those data. For example, below is the XSD I created for the above payload.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://oscar.pactera.com/icms/schema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="CourtEvent.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="InvestigationOfficer.xsd"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="FileApplication">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ApplicationNo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="ApplicationType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="CourtOrderRefNo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="SourceRequestNo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseNo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="RejectionCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="RejectionReason" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>

            <xsd:element name="CourtEventDetails" type="CourtEvent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="IODetails" type="InvestigationOfficer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="ReturnOfFileApplicationDetails" type="FileApplication"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

The problem I have now is that my IDE is complaining that it cannot find the complex type `FileApplication` I put in for the `ReturnOfFileApplicationDetails` element the even though they are literally in the same XSD. Since the `CourtEvent.xsd` and the `InvestigationOfficer.xsd` also come with no `targetNamespace`, my IDE cannot find the `CourtEvent` and the `InvestigationOfficer` complex types as well.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me I properly build my XSD without `targetNamespace`.

Cheers,

James Tran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the default namespace declaration

```
xmlns="http://oscar.pactera.com/icms/schema"
```